# Can't manipulate parsed string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a parser to get address and zip code from a webpage using python. My parser is running specklessly. The result is coming in two lines. However, I'm very weak in manipulating string. So, if anybody helps me on this, I would be 
very grateful. Thanks.

Here is the script:

```
import requests ; from lxml import html

link = "http://www.greenthumbnyc.org/gardensearch.html#map-canvas"

def green_thumb(base_link):
    response = requests.get(base_link)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    title = tree.cssselect(".garden-info p")[0].text_content().replace("More information","")
    print(title)

green_thumb(link)
```

Results I'm having:

```
138th Street Community Garden (El Girasol)
624-638 East 138th Street
```

Results I would like to have:

```
138th Street Community Garden (El Girasol) 624-638 East 138th Street
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `.replace("\n","")`

```
title = tree.cssselect(".garden-info p")[0].text_content().replace("More information","").replace("\n","")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Paul Wilson, for your answer. It worked. I did the same thing in the first place but got an indentation error. Strange. Gonna accept it in a while.

Comment: Btw, do you have any idea how to keep the first or last portion of the string and shake off the rest? I tried with a wrong logic as index but that should not work [:\n]. Thanks.

Comment: You could split the string into two using `.split("\n")` and use the part that you want.

Comment: This is exactly what i expected. .split("\n")[0] You deserve an upvote. Thanks for everything.